# Read specific column of csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv

The code is working fine but it is creating list of values in braces. I want to modify the code in such a way that it prints as in csv in proper column and row format.

Expected output :

```
Ver Total 

4     5

4     5

4     5

4     5
```

Actual Output:

```
(ver,total) (4,5) (4,5) (4,5)
```

Here is the following code

```
import csv
f = open("a.csv", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
data = []
for line in f:
    cells = line.split(",")
    data.append((cells[0], cells[3]))
print data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import csv

with open('a.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rowcnt = 0
    for row in reader:
        if rowcnt == 0:
            print row[0], row[1]
        else:
            print row[0], '  ', row[1]
        rowcnt = rowcnt + 1
```

Provides the following output:

```
Ver Stat
4    5
4    5
4    5
```

Comment: it gives the error......Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\project\csvcol.py", line 17, in <module>
    for row in reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: any help is highly appriciated

Comment: Anyone can help this

Comment: please somebody help this issue... M stuck

Comment: Indent the for block within the with block.

Comment: I have indented the code above...try now...and let me know